# bind cache not used?

Tags: bind, time, query

i installed a classic bind9 dns server inside a local network, working as a forwarding dns server,
there is my config file (i just added my ISP DNS servers as forwarders):

> options {
>
> directory "/var/cache/bind";
>
> forwarders {
>         212.27.40.240;
>         212.27.40.241;  };
>
> forward only;
>
> dnssec-validation auto;
>
> auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
>
> listen-on-v6 { any; }; };

my point of interest is the "Query time" obtained when using dig

i used   **dig @my_dns_ipadress www.google.com**

i also added the time when was sent the query

06:04:47 --> ;; Query time: 157 msec   (first query after bind was started)

06:09:24 --> ;; Query time: 1 msec

06:29:28 --> ;; Query time: 106 msec

06:39:39 --> ;; Query time: 1 msec

07:04:21 --> ;; Query time: 98 msec

my question is, why the 3rd and 5th query time are not around 1 msec ?
the cache did not seems to be used

I also performed these tests while dumping outgoing udp 53 packets toward my isp dns server
and i found that when the query time is above 1 or 2 msec, bind sent dns requests to my isp dns server.

So how can i force bind to use his cache ?

Answer (score 1):

bind cannot cache a record for more time than the record's TTL (time to live). www.google.com has a TTL of 5 minutes, therefore the cached record will expire after that much time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by using unbound dns server, setting the "cache-min-ttl" option to 604800 seconds (1 week).
The cache is always used during one week, Qery time is between 1 and 3 ms